# Honda adaptive cruise control

Tags: honda, crv, cruise-control

My daily commute can be very slow. Sometimes I use adaptive cruise control, sometimes I don't.

What I have normally seen is even if I don't press gas pedal, my car can reach to speeds up to 10 miles per hour, which is very fast for my commute. During commute time, I end up using brakes to slowdown the car. Sizable chunk of commute is basically slowing the car without providing any gas

Does anyone know when using adaptive cruise, if the car uses brakes in slow speeds or controls the speed by right amount of gas. I'm thinking it might have better control on engine and may not have to use brakes.

My assumption here is this is going to cause my brakes to wear soon

Comment: 10 miles per hour? You speed devil! Do you mean 100 miles per hour or some other figure?

Comment: @CJDennis, welcome to my commute, it's 10 mph or less in certain 5 miles stretch of my commute and not a mistake

Comment: My Honda's cruise control can't be used below about 40 km/h (25 mph).